# "scicosim: error. Type 0 not yet supported for outtb." how to solve this problem?

Tags: c, scilab

I'm having an incomprehensible problem in Scicoslab in the last few days.
I've been writing some communication blocks (to send data to an external application) for scicos in C and then wrap them with it's own code. The problem is that, even if the code is working (I've checked every output possible), scicos gives me this error message: `sicosim: error. Type 0 not yet supported by outtb.` [Error Screenshot](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/3861/scicoserror.png)


Here is the code for the c function of the Sensor Dispatcher Block:

```
    int bro_sens_send (scicos_block *block)
{
    int rc, i;
    bro_fist_t packet[BUFFER_SIZE];

    for (i = 1; i < block->nin; i++) {
        bro_encode_sci_datablock(&packet[i-1], block->inptr[i]);
    };

    printf ("Data for first block: %i, %i, %.2f\n", packet[0].port, packet[0].operation, packet[0].data);

    rc = send(block->inptr[0][0], packet, sizeof(bro_fist_t) * BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

    if (rc < 0)
    {
        perror("send() failed");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%d bytes of data were sent\n", rc);
    return 0;
}

int bro_sens_read (scicos_block *block)
{
    int rc, i;
    bro_fist_t packet[BUFFER_SIZE];

    rc = recv(block->inptr[0][0], packet, sizeof(bro_fist_t) * BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    printf("%d bytes of data were received\n", rc);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        perror("recv() failed");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Starting to set outputs :3 [%i]\n", block->nout);

    for (i = 0; i < block->nout; i++) {
        printf("Next Step defining outputs :D [%i]\n", i);
        bro_decode_sci_datablock(&packet[i], &block->outptr[i][0]);
        printf("Output value for port %i is: %.2f[%i]\n", i, block->outptr[i][0], block->outsz[(2*block->nout)+i]);

    }

    return 0;
}

void bro_comm_sens_disp (scicos_block *block, int flag)
{
    switch (flag) {
        case 1: /* set output */
            bro_sens_send(block);
            bro_sens_read(block);
            break;
        case 2: /* get input */
            break;
        case 4: /* initialisation */
            break;
        case 5: /* ending */
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the block definition (In scilab code):

```
function [x,y,typ] = SENS_Disp(job,arg1,arg2)
    x=[];y=[];typ=[];
    select job
    case 'plot' then
        exprs=arg1.graphics.exprs;

        standard_draw(arg1)
    case 'getinputs' then
        [x,y,typ]=standard_inputs(arg1)
    case 'getoutputs' then
        [x,y,typ]=standard_outputs(arg1)
    case 'getorigin' then
        [x,y]=standard_origin(arg1)
    case 'set' then
        x=arg1
        model=arg1.model;graphics=arg1.graphics;
        exprs=graphics.exprs;
    case 'define' then
        model       = scicos_model()
        model.sim   = list('bro_comm_sens_disp',4)
        model.out   = [1;1;1;1;1;1;1]
        model.out2  = [1;1;1;1;1;1;1]
        model.outtyp= [1;1;1;1;1;1;1]
        model.in    = [1;3;3;3;3;3;3;3]
        model.in2   = [1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1]
        model.intyp = [3;1;1;1;1;1;1;1]
        model.evtin = []
        model.rpar  = []
        model.ipar  = []
        model.dstate=[1];
        model.blocktype='c'
        model.dep_ut=[%t %f]
        exprs=[]
        gr_i=['xstringb(orig(1),orig(2),[''Sensors'';+''Dispatcher''],sz(1),sz(2),''fill'');']
        x=standard_define([3 2],model,exprs,gr_i)
    end
endfunction
```

The first inpput port for the block is the socket descriptor for communications while the other seven are connected to setup blocks. The outputs returns the data received from the external application.
I've tried to navigate through Scilab code and I've understood that the error I'm getting tells me that the type of data has been set wrongly, but I've checked and it's not quite the case.
Here is the code of Scicoslab that outputs the error:

```
/*set vectors of outtb*/
                for (j=0; j<nlnk; j++) { /*for each link*/
                        subheader=(int *)(listentry(il_state_outtb,j+1)); /*get header of outtbl(j+1)*/
                        outtbsz[j]=subheader[1]; /*store dimensions*/
                        outtbsz[j+nlnk]=subheader[2];

                        switch (subheader[0]) { /*store type and address*/
                                /*matrix of double*/
                        case 1  :
                                switch (subheader[3]) {
                                case 0  :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSREAL_N;  /*double real matrix*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSREAL_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                case 1  :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSCOMPLEX_N;  /*double complex matrix*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSCOMPLEX_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                default :
                                        Scierror(888,\
                                                 "%s : error. Type %d of double scalar matrix not yet supported "
                                                 "for outtb.\n",\
                                                 fname,subheader[3]);
                                        FREE(outtbptr);
                                        FREE(outtbtyp);
                                        FREE(outtbsz);
                                        FREE(opar);
                                        FREE(oparsz);
                                        FREE(opartyp);
                                        FREE(oz);
                                        FREE(ozsz);
                                        FREE(oztyp);
                                        FREE(lfunpt);
                                        freeparam;
                                        FREE(outtb_elem);
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;

                                /*matrix of integers*/
                        case 8  :
                                switch (subheader[3]) {
                                case 1  :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSINT8_N;  /*int8*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSINT8_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                case 2  :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSINT16_N;  /*int16*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSINT16_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                case 4  :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSINT32_N;  /*int32*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSINT32_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                case 11 :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSUINT8_N; /*uint8*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSUINT8_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                case 12 :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSUINT16_N; /*uint16*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSUINT16_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                case 14 :
                                        outtbtyp[j]=SCSUINT32_N; /*uint32*/
                                        outtbptr[j]=(SCSUINT32_COP *)(subheader+4);
                                        break;

                                default :
                                        Scierror(888,\
                                                 "%s : error. Type %d of integer scalar matrix not yet supported "
                                                 "for outtb.\n",\
                                                 fname,subheader[3]);
                                        FREE(outtbptr);
                                        FREE(outtbtyp);
                                        FREE(outtbsz);
                                        FREE(opar);
                                        FREE(oparsz);
                                        FREE(opartyp);
                                        FREE(oz);
                                        FREE(ozsz);
                                        FREE(oztyp);
                                        FREE(lfunpt);
                                        freeparam;
                                        FREE(outtb_elem);
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;

                        default :
                                Scierror(888,"%s : error. Type %d not yet supported for outtb.\n",fname,subheader[0]);
                                FREE(outtbptr);
                                FREE(outtbtyp);
                                FREE(outtbsz);
                                FREE(opar);
                                FREE(oparsz);
                                FREE(opartyp);
                                FREE(oz);
                                FREE(ozsz);
                                FREE(oztyp);
                                FREE(lfunpt);
                                freeparam;
                                FREE(outtb_elem);
                                return 0;
                                break;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After a lot of time I've solved the problem. There was a function that was setting a value in a wrong memory space. The problem was that there weren't any error messages nor warnings.
The problem was in a function that did this:

```
block->outptr[0][3] = 0;
```

In a block that had only 3 output ports. This wrote the wrong data inside the data registry. After I removed it everything works fine.